# Dependencies of subproject can not be resolved for dependent project (but are resolved when building subproject itself)

Tags: java, gradle

Following the explanation in ["Building and Testing with Gradle"](http://www.gradleware.com/registered/books/building-and-testing/multi-project-builds.html#ch6) I have a multiproject gradle setup like this:

```
rootFolder
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
    EMS
        build.gradle
    cloud-sdk
        build.gradle
```

The `cloud-sdk` project depends on several jars, partially resolved via maven partially via locale jars:

```
// file: cloud-sdk/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group:'org.apache.tomcat', name:'tomcat-catalina', version:'7.0.47'
    compile group:'org.mongodb', name:'mongo-java-driver', version:'2.11.3'
    compile group:'com.google.code.gson', name:'gson', version:'2.2.4'
    compile group:'com.thoughtworks.xstream', name:'xstream', version:'1.4.6'
    compile fileTree(dir:'lib/', include:'JavaPNS_2.2.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir:'lib/', include:'gcm-server.jar')
}
```

The `EMS`-project depends on the cloud-sdk which I think should be defined like this:

```
// file: EMS/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile project(':cloud-sdk')
}
```

Furthermore, my root build.gradle and settings.gradle files look like this:

settings.gradle

```
include 'cloud-sdk', 'EMS'
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile project(':EMS')
}
```

In this case I am not sure whether I also need the dependency `compile project (':cloud-sdk')`. I tried both version but since I get the same error message in both cases I assume it doesn't matter.

When I try to run the script from the rootFolder via `gradle build` I get the following error messages:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':EMS:compile'.
> Could not find org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina:7.0.47.
  Required by:
    rootFolder:EMS:unspecified > rootFolder:cloud-sdk:unspecified
> Could not find org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.11.3.
  Required by:
    rootFolder:EMS > rootFolder:cloud-sdk:unspecified
> Could not find com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4.
  Required by:
    rootFolder:EMS > rootFolder:cloud-sdk:unspecified
> Could not find com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.6.
  Required by:
    rootFolder:EMS:unspecified > rootFolder:cloud-sdk:unspecified
```

But when I just build the cloud-sdk project via `gradle cloud-sdk:build` gradle downloads the required jars and builds the project without a problem.

But even if I try `gradle build` after that, although gradle notices that the `cloud-sdk` project is already up-to-date, it complains about the missing dependencies.

Why is that? It downloaded them already so they should be available somewhere and even if not the `cloud-sdk` knows what it needs and how to fetch it. What am I missing? Do I need to specify the dependencies in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it turns out gradle could not fetch the dependencies in the `EMS` project since I did not specify any repositories to fetch them from. I assumed that would not be necessary since the only dependencies I needed it to fetch were declared in the `cloud-sdk` project and *that* did have a repository given.

This is basically the solution to my problem, but if anybody can explain to me why it is necessary to specify the repository *again* or explain why it is a bug in gradle that should be fixed, I'll accept that answer as it would answer the "why" and not just the "how do I get it to work".

Comment: What did you insert in the repositories section of the EMS project?

Comment: I just copied it from the `cloud-sdk` project: `repositories {     mavenCentral() }`

Comment: I had forgot mine as well. Thanks